# argument type mismatch @onmessage

Tags: jakarta-ee, java-websocket

I create a `@ServerEndpoint` and `Decoders` and `Encoders`.

the server get me an error: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch` when I am sending object by using `session.sendObject(message)` to server

I vary goggled but cannot find problem.
this is my `serverEndpoint`

```
@ServerEndpoint(value="/room" 
        , encoders = MessageEncoder.class
        , decoders = MessageDecoder.class)
public class myServerEndpoint 
{
    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(Message message, Session session)
    {
       //some code to proccess message
    }
}
```

and this is my MessageDecoder:

```
public class MessageDecoder implements Decoder.Text<Message> 
{
     public Message decode(String str) throws DecodeException 
     {
         JsonObject obj = Json
                .createReader(new StringReader(str)).readObject();

         Message msg = new Message();
         msg.setMessage(obj.getString("message"));
         msg.setSender(obj.getString("sender"));
         msg.setReceivedDate((Date) obj.get("receivedDate"));

         return msg;
     }
     //... and other Methods
}
```

and this is my `Message.class`:

```
public class Message implements Serializable
{
    private String message;
    private String sender;
    private Date receivedDate;

    public Message() {}
    //setters and getters
}
```

and this is my client code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    WebSocketContainer container = ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer();
    Session session = container
            .connectToServer(WSClient.class,
             URI.create("ws://localhost:8080/mySocket/room"));

    Message msg = new Message();
    msg.setMessage("msg");
    msg.setSender("me");
    msg.setReceivedDate(new Date());

    session.getBasicRemote().sendObject(msg);
}
```

a problem occurred when I am trying to send Object to server and server say `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch`.

what is problem?

Answer (score 0):

I finally find my problem.

the `willDecode` function in `MessageTextDecode` class was return `false` and the `serverEndpoint` was say `argument type mismatch`.

the function should return `true` if the string is not have problem.

```
public boolean willDecode(String arg0) 
{
    return true;  // in previous my code this returned false 
}
```